# How to create a stretchy rig for LEGO?

Tags: mesh, rigging

I'm creating a superhero story using rigged LEGO figures, but some of my characters are elastic like Mr. Fantastic, but every time I try to stretch it, the mesh always gets messed up. Usually looking like this: [image] How do I fix it? Here is the file: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pq8ODCeJnjQi6GDj4eZm-IjIjkC2DKH7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: looks like your model doesn't have enough geometry. Did you try subdiv modifier? if that doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Comment: Try the link now,

Comment: Sorry, thr file is still private.

Comment: Try the link now

Comment: Hm,  sorry, still doesn't work. I can see now the file name and google tries to generate a preview (which never works for blend files) but there is no download button at all. There should be one but there isn't one. Just details and it works neither.